# Playing Multiple Sound effects isssue in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Please help if someone faced this issue. I have a sound effect 3sec long which need to be played repeatedly for some time of 10 to 15 secs. Implemented like below:
`SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect(powerUpSound, true);`

But when I play an another sound effect, previous sound (`powerUpSound`) effect stops.
`SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect(starsSouns, false);`

Any help will be appreciated. Cocos2d-x v2.2.3

Comment: two different sound file ?

Comment: yes two different sound files.